# Terminal says "PyObjCTools" doesn't exist when it does

Tags: python, macos, py2app, pyobjc

I am attempting to build a Python application on OSX 10.10, I have used MacPorts to install all dependencies and have used PyCharm to write the application. When I run it from PyCharm everything works fine, but when I try to run the build script, when it comes to the py2app part it tells me that the directory ".../PyObjC/PyObjCTools" isn't there, but I can navigate to it in Finder and it's very clearly there. Does anyone have any idea what my problem could be? I've been running around in circles with this for a week now.

Comment: can you show us the setup.py?

Comment: Are you using the /same python/?

Answer (score 0):

If it's access to the PyObjCTools functionality you want, you should import it the Python way, for example:

```
from PyObjCTools import AppHelper
```

If you need to access actual files, it's possible to force `py2app` to add files using the setup `data_files` options. For example:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
app=['main.py'],
name="App Name",
data_files=['/path/to/folder'],
setup_requires=['py2app'],
options=dict(py2app=dict(iconfile='en.lproj/icon.icns',
                         includes=['includename'],
                         packages=['packagename']
                         )   
             )   
)
```

After a rebuild the files are located inside the Cocoa bundle **Resources** folder, which you can find using the `resourcePath()` function:

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath()
```